# Can a kernel exploit compromise an OpenVZ host?

Tags: exploit, virtualization, kernel

As OpenVZ runs on a lot of virtual servers, I would like to know how kernel exploits would affect the whole system. Would it be possible to break out of an OpenVZ container (virtuozzo, etc) with a kernel exploit?

Answer (score 12):

OpenVZ containers do not have their own kernels. In OpenVZ, there is only one kernel for the host OS and all of the containers. Successfully exploiting that kernel from within a container means potential impact to the OpenVZ host and all of its containers. If you want to avoid this vulnerability, you need a real hypervisor that boots in independent kernel for each virtual machine.