# Security advanatages to running a webapp inside a container, which is ALSO inside a vm?

Tags: virtualization

I am doing some security consulting for a client who intends on deploying a Ruby on Rails web application. I am trying to ascertain a couple of different things...

Is it any more secure to run an application inside a container which is also inside of a virtual machine? I *think* that in addition to the deployment conveniences that containerized applications provide, it may add yet another layer of abstraction, but I am not sure. On the other hand, if I am already deploying a virtual machine for my application which separates the kernel, hardware, namespace, etc -- is it actually extraneous to then deploy a container on top of that? Furthermore, does using a container actually introduce security concerns in and of itself?

The only obvious thing that comes to mind is that it's usually not in the interest of operational security to deploy a technology that you do not know how to properly configure, and I am not super experienced with containers (I do use them for software development quite frequently however). For instance, I know that I know nothing about IPV6 so I disable it entirely and instead focus on locking down my IPV4 connection, which I am comfortable doing.

Are there any other reasons not to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is a container and how does it work?

A container is simply a way to run multiple processes on a system that expect to have full root privileges, but which should not *actually* be permitted to perform sensitive configuration changes or interfere with other processes outside of the container. When a process makes a system call, the kernel will traditionally check its privileges (such as UID and GID) and either grant or deny the request. When running in a container, the kernel will set up a "namespace", and any administrative actions will only take effect within that one namespaces. Certain actions, such as changing system-wide configurations, are not possible even with root in a container.

Containers can cause severe security issues when privileged processes run under them. If your application is not privileged and cannot influence or hijack another privileged process running under the same container, it won't be able to take advantage of a container's intrinsic weaknesses. This just means that the container won't *necessarily* reduce security, but it will also not *improve* it.

I give a long description of multiple sandboxing technologies in [another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175373/106285), including information on containers that can be found under the heading "Containers".

### Is a container the right solution here?

> Is it any more secure to run an application inside a container which is also inside of a virtual machine?

There is no difference. The container does not add any extra security barrier or force the attacker to go through any extra steps. Regardless of which of the two setups you choose, the attacker will only have to compromise the application, compromise the kernel, then escape the VM. The **only** reason to use a container is if you want to run multiple processes that each believe they are root on the same system, without giving them sufficient privileged access to interfere with the other processes.

> Furthermore, does using a container actually introduce security concerns in and of itself?

Yes, using a container can introduce security concerns if a compromise of the host kernel is a threat. This is because a compromised container kernel [compromises the host](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/199906/106285) as well. Instead, you should be sandboxing the untrusted application to minimize the attack surface area that is exposed to it.

> The only obvious thing that comes to mind is that it's usually not in the interest of operational security to deploy a technology that you do not know how to properly configure, and I am not super experienced with containers

That is another reason not to use containers in this situation. If you don't know what *extra* privileges you may be granting containerized processes that wouldn't be granted otherwise, you shouldn't try to run one. Containers have a purpose and they can be configured fairly securely and used to enhance the security of a system, but simply *using* them is not enough and won't magically improve security.

### Can container technology be used to improve security?

Containers on Linux are typically built on top of [namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) or analogous implementations (e.g. OpenVZ). While a full container may not improve security at all, namespace technology can be used to reduce attack surface area. For example, a network namespace will allow you to isolate network interfaces from the application, and a PID namespace will hide other processes from it so it cannot interact with them. Namespaces, along with other techniques such as seccomp and mandatory access controls, can be used to reduce the attack surface area (of both the kernel and other processes) that is exposed to the untrusted application.

Comment: Very thorough, thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to know. What is a good solution or sandboxing an application in a vm?

Comment: @Chev_603 The same solutions that would help with sandboxing it without using a VM, which itself depends on the particular application. Mandatory access controls (like AppArmor), capability dropping (if the process has privileges), and seccomp are all very useful.